# Masking away an area of a terrain surface in OpenGL

Tags: c++, 3d, opengl-es, terrain

I'm working on a 3D geographical renderer with building models on a terrain surface. These building models are captured through photogrammetry, and a problem we have is that the terrain surface sometimes pokes through the building model since the surface data and building model don't match exactly.

We want to mask away the terrain surface in the area that is covered by the building model footprint. I've been thinking of using the stencil buffer, maybe extruding some kind of shadow volume from the model and filling the z buffer with high values in the area covered by the building model's footprint before rendering the model. This would require quite a bit of processing though, and I'm hoping that there is smarter and more efficient way of doing things. Another idea is making an orthographic 2d texture of the model rendered from above and using this to fill the z-buffer in some creative way using shaders.

So if anyone have done something similar before or have any ideas, I'd be real glad to hear them :-)

I'm limited to OpenGL ES 3.0, so I can't use geometry shaders or other fancy features.

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: Is it an option to draw the buildings _first_ and then the terrain? Alternatively, can you draw the buildings with `glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS)`?

Comment: I still need the building model to have depth testing, both internally and against the surrounding terrain, so i don't think this would work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You must know both the terrain mesh, and where the buildings actually are on the terrain. The most obvious fix would be to preprocess the terrain mesh to "flatten" the area around the foundations of each building. This only needs doing once, so it's only a one-off cost rather than a per-frame cost.

Can't think of any immediately obvious neater method - the need for depth testing, except when you don't want it, doesn't really nicely turn into an algorithm ;)

Comment: That is exactly how I would do it to